# Loading jquery after click on certain element

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with a jquery code and I hope someone from the community may help.

I have a google map and there's a tiny bit of text assigned to each marker. What I'd like to achieve is, hide the text that comes after "-" in the map marker info window.

Hey everyone, I have a problem with a jquery code and I hope someone from the community may help.

I have a google map and there's a tiny bit of text assigned to each marker. What I'd like to achieve is, hide the text that comes after "-" in the map marker info window.

I've written the below code which works just fine when I enter in on the console, however it needs to be loaded after someone clicks on the marker since the span is only visible then. I tried to achieve that using on.click function with no luck.

The example page I need help with can be accessed [here](https://www.kisnisvesaire.com/test-page/?cmp_bypass=taslak1), and the code I run on the console is below. As I said, it works but only when the infowindow is open / aka when the marker is clicked on.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

    $( "p.info").each(function() {$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/-.*$/, ''));});
});`
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try replacing the `-` with `\-`, because in regex, the hyphen typically denotes a _range_, such as `A-Z` or `0-9`.